# Kendo CSS icon location

Tags: html, css, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have changed the font size on my Kendo grid to 11 and by doing so, the calendar icon on a datepicker textbox gets cut off at the bottom. I was able to move the icon up using margin-top when you hover over it with the following code, however I am not able to figure out how to get it moved up in just its normal state.

```
    .k-link:not(.k-state-disabled):hover>.k-i-calendar,.k-state-hover .k-i-calendar,.k-button:hover .k-i-calendar,.k-textbox:hover .k-i-calendar,.k-button:active .k-i-calendar{
background-position:-48px -176px; margin-top: -6px;
}
```

See example: http://jsbin.com/ufimom/592/edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

```
.k-i-calendar {
    background-position: -32px -176px;
    margin-top: -6px !important;
}
```

**Demo** : http://jsbin.com/ufimom/596/edit

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your html and background image in context, I'm just taking a guess here. Try appending the normal state of the calender icon to your css rule like this,

```
.k-link:not(.k-state-disabled):hover>.k-i-calendar,.k-state-hover .k-i-calendar,.k-button:hover .k-i-calendar,.k-textbox:hover .k-i-calendar,.k-button:active .k-i-calendar, .k-i-calendar { background-position:-48px -176px; margin-top: -6px; }
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/EVOlUWi/1/)

**EDIT**: As the previous poster mentioned, !important is likely the best solution here, in order to override the Kendo settings. Example:

```
.k-i-calendar {
 margin-top: 0px !important;
}
```

DEMO here: http://jsbin.com/ufimom/598/

Comment: Same, except I appended (, .k-i-calendar) to the rule, at the very end.

Comment: I see you added a jsbin demo. Now that I can see the context, I'll edit within that.

Answer (score 0):

I have a highly personalized Kendo stuff. Custom styling is one of the biggest problems of kendo (along with million other issues that you will find once you start using kendo at a big scale). To minimize the size of the stylesheets they have combined a lot of styling of different controls into few files. Although its a good thing but it makes the custom styling (and then updating in the future) a nightmare. Knowing how ":not", ">", ":first", ":first-of-type", etc. work in css will really help you with styling of the grids and other controls.

I usually write separate stylesheets to override kendo styling (by using a lot of !important keyword in my override css). It helps when I update kendo.

Comment: I added a link for a jsbin that shows the effect of what happens when you hover.

Comment: Not sure if its my office firewall that is blocking it but I keep getting the 502 Bad Gateway error when I click on the jsbin link. Will try it later on another machine.